# Home Page Applications Show Up with Numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, cache

I am sure there is a stupid easy fix for this, but when I have added an app to my home screen before, and take it down, when I try to upload it again it titles it as if it were a new version "Example Library (1)" rather than "Example Library". This is really annoying as it kills the aesthetic of my home page but I am not entirely sure how to fix this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint remembers the other web parts you've added before, but sees them as "closed".

To see a list where you can select and delete unused web parts, navigate to your page's URL but with "?Contents=1" appended. Example:

```
Homepage.aspx?Contents=1
```

Find the items where "Open On Page?" is No and delete them.